# Change cart totals title text on cart page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking to change the text "Cart Totals" in the cart totals div in WooCommerce or remove it totally with an action.

I've added different text above the box in using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_totals', 'custom_before_cart_totals' );
function custom_before_cart_totals() {
        echo '<h2>Checkout</h2>';                                                
}
```

But I cant find a way to remove the default wording "Cart Totals" other than editing a WooCommerce template or target and hiding with css, but would love something that I can place in the functions file to either change the old text or remove it completely.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[Default Cart Totals Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i65dg.png)

Comment: Hi Donny Dug, WooCommerce not provided any Hook to change cart totals text..
Either you can hide this text through css. or you need to change text in WooCommerce Cart Page template file..

Comment: Yes, thats the issue, however Loics answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible using the WordPress filter hook `gettext`.

1) Removing "Cart totals":

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_cart_totals_text', 20, 3 );
function change_cart_totals_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Cart totals' ){
        $translated = '';
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

2) Replace *(or change)* "Cart totals":

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_cart_totals_text', 20, 3 );
function change_cart_totals_text( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_cart() && $translated == 'Cart totals' ){
        $translated = __('Your custom text', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Or you can remove it from the Woocommerce template `cart/cart_totals.php`

Comment: Legend, this is exactly what we were looking for, it works perfectly.
thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to remove the `<h2></h2>`as well?

Answer (score 3):

```php
function change_cart_totals($translated){
  $translated = str_ireplace('Cart Totals', 'Cart Total', $translated);
  return $translated;
}
add_filter('gettext', 'change_cart_totals' );
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate the `cart-totals.php` theme from woocommerce into your own theme, and replace this line:

```
<h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Cart totals', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```